# How to send canvas object to java using ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, canvas, http-request-parameters

I want to send a canvas image object to the server using ajax.
After creating the canvas image

```
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "uploadProfPic",
    data: { userId: user, imgBase64: dataURL }
})
```

in the controller I tried like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadProfPic",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody uploadProfPic(@RequestParam(value="imageBase64", defaultValue="")String imageBase64, String userId){

    return userId;
}
```

In @RequestParam what will i write to get the canvas object?

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestParam String imgBase64
```

As you are transmitting the data as a string.